# PHP 8.1 fastcgi exe is not available in non thread safe version

Tags: php, fastcgi, iis-10, php-8.1

I'm upgrading my php from 7.2 to 8.1 to be used with IIS FastCgi.
When I download Non Thread Safe version from below url, as recommended by PHP for IIS FastCGI, the php-cgi.exe is not available in the downloaded folder.

https://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-8.1.2-nts-Win32-vs16-x64.zip

If I download thread safe version then it's there.

In php download page it says,
IIS
If you are using PHP as FastCGI with IIS you should use the Non-Thread Safe (NTS) versions of PHP.

https://windows.php.net/download#php-8.1

Can someone please advice me what is the correct way to do this?

I have attached how I set up FastCgi in my IIS.

[image: IIS set up]

Answer (score 1):

I download PHP 8.1 from the link you shared in the original post.

I could see the **php-cgi.exe** in the folder.

[image]

I suggest you again download the zip file and check on you side.

Comment: Hi Deepak, Thank you very much. For some reason in my first extract it has not created this file. But when I extract second time it did.